# how to set Log rotate in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, logfile

Right now I'm using a single log file, but there is requirement to make it daily , but for the current date, the file name must be laravel.log

```html
laravel-2020-08-30.log
laravel-2020-08-31.log
laravel-202-009-01.log  -> the current date must be laravel.log
```

`

Is it possible to get the logs daily, but named like this?

**laravel.log**

While the older (up to a week) are named like this:

**laravel-2020-08-30.log**

Comment: Laravel is provide formate like `FILE_PER_DAY (Y-m-d), FILE_PER_MONTH (Y-m), FILE_PER_YEAR (Y)`.  You can set one of the date formats using slashes, underscores and/or dots instead of dashes. let me know what actual you have required.

Comment: i want the log create daily, the current date log file will be laravel.log and the previous date separate based on the date ig laravel-2020-01-01.log

Comment: You want the Log file name like `laravel-2020-01-01.log`. right?

Comment: yes for the previous date, but for the current date only laravel.log without yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 3):

You can try given solution for you problem.

Update your `.env` file.

```
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

then you can run following this command on your terminal inside project root directory.

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache
```

Now you can check your `storage` folder inside `logs` directory with following name conversion.

For ex:
`laravel-2020-09-01.log`

Comment: why `cache:clear` ... why do people keep telling people to clear their "cache store" ... and you don't need to clear the config to just cache it, you can just cache it `config:cache`, but if you are developing locally, there is no reason to ever cache your config or routes

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I am agree with you but some It will be get all configuration values so that It will be batter to clear cache.